# Typescript Can't resolve custom paths imports

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I'm working on a `PHP` project using `Typescript` and I'm trying to follow the same pattern for monorepo, similar to what `NX` does. I'm having issues when trying to compile `typescript` for each `apps`.

This is my current structure:

```
.
├── apps/
│   ├── project-a/
│   ├── project-b/
│   └── project-c/
│       └── src/
│           ├── sass
│           └── ts/
│               ├── components/
│               └── index.ts
├── libs/
│   └── typescript/
│       ├── interface/
│       ├── abstract/
│       │   └── base.ts
│       └── components/
│           ├── header.ts
│           └── footer.ts
├── webpack/
│   └── dev.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "AMD",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "@libs/abstract": ["libs/typescript/abstract"],
      "@libs/interface": ["libs/typescript/interface"],
      "@libs/components": ["libs/typescript/components"],
    }
  }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is this:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@libs/components' in '**\apps\project-c\src\ts';
>
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration resolve as module.
>
> **\apps\project-c\src\ts\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

Basically I need to have basic functionality that is going to be used by all `apps` from the `libs` folder, but when I try to compile the project, I'm getting that error.

My webpack script is running with arguments to define and locate the app that needs to be compiled, for example:

> yarn dev --theme=project-c

Which is going to build the path structure to the proper project. If I remove any imports from the `libs`, it's compiling as expected, but as soon as I try to import, for example, the Header component, it fails.

I imagine it must be something with my `tsconfig.json` settings, but none of the fixes I tried worked. Even tried to "copy" from an official NX monorepo settings, but still nothing.

Comment: related? dup? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70902895/11107541

Comment: @starball thanks. This question helped me find a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem, I was able to find a fix, thanks to @starball comment and a little bit more research with the info found on that question.

Basically I had to add a couple more configs to webpack in order to make it work. Check the following adjustments necessary.

```js
module.exports = () => ({
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../libs/typescript')]
      },
      // ...
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@libs/abstract': path.resolve(__dirname, '../libs/typescript/abstract'),
      '@libs/interface': path.resolve(__dirname, '../libs/typescript/interface'),
      '@libs/components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../libs/typescript/components'),
    }
  },
});
```

On webpack I had to add a resolve property, with the same alias as defined in tsconfig.json (this one only make the IDE works, not the compiler). And also a new rules, to include the generic path for all libs typescript files.